# How to use Azure Managed Identity in Azure Function to access Service Bus with a trigger?

Tags: triggers, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I have created a ServiceBus namespace in Azure, along with a topic and a subscription. I also have a simple Azure version 1 function that triggers on a received topic in the ServiceBus, like this:

```
[FunctionName("MyServiceBusTriggerFunction")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myTopic", "mySubscription", Connection = "MyConnection")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

The function triggers nicely for the topics in the ServiceBus when I define the connection string in functions Application Settings by using Shared Access Policy for topic, like this:

```
Endpoint=sb://MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=mypolicy;SharedAccessKey=UZ...E0=
```

Now, instead of Shared Access Keys, I would like to use Managed Service Identity (MSI) for accessing the ServiceBus. According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/services-support-msi) it should be possible, unless I have misunderstood something. I haven't managed to get it working though.

What I tried, was to

- set the Managed Service Identity "On" for my function in Azure portal
- give Owner role for the function in ServiceBus Access Control section in Azure Portal
- set the connection string for MyFunction like this: *Endpoint=sb://MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/*

The function is not triggering in this set-up, so what am I missing or what am I doing wrong?
I'd be grateful for any advice to help me get further. Thanks.

Comment: i doubt thats how it works. i think its only used to allow the code to connect to the resource. i dont think you can use MSI for polling on the function level

Comment: So if I wanted to use MSI for accessing ServiceBus from an Azure Function, I would need to create e.g. a timer triggered function and poll ServiceQueue from within it.

Comment: i'm not sure really, so dont take my word for it, but I really doubt MSI can replace connection string for this scenario

Comment: As mentioned one trick is to use Key Vault to hold the connection strings, native MSI is not supported for triggers as yet and there's an [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37907848-support-for-azure-managed-service-identities-in-ev) item to register interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

You may mix up with MSI and Shared Access Policy.They are using **different provider to access to Azure servicebus**. You could just use connectionstring or just use MSI to authenticate.

When you use `Managed Service Identity`(MSI) to authenticate, you need to create a token provider for the managed service identity with the following code.

`TokenProvider.CreateManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider(ServiceAudience.ServiceBusAudience)`.

This [**TokenProvider**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity)'s implementation uses the `AzureServiceTokenProvider` found in the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` library. `AzureServiceTokenProvider` will follow a set number of different methods, depending on the environment, to get an access token. And then initialize client to operate the servicebus.
For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet/).

When you use servicebus connectionstring to access which using the Shared Access Token (SAS) token provider, so you can operate directly.

Comment: An Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger requires a connection string as an argument. When it is triggered to run, it already needs to be authorized. It is too late to create a TokenProvider for MSI at that point, so looks like I can not use it. I thought MSI was supposed to handle access tokens behind the scenes, but that does not seem to be the case. Right?

Comment: Actually that! You could not use MSI to authenticate servicebus trigger function.

Comment: There is a built-in way now with the latest package, please see my answer below

Answer (score 9):

**Update for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` version 5.x**

There is now an offical docs for the latest version of the package in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme-pre).

```
{
  "Values": {
    "<connection_name>__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "<service_bus_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**Previous answer**:

This actually seems to be possible now, at least worked just fine for me. You need to use this connection string:

```
Endpoint=sb://service-bus-namespace-name.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity
```

I have not actually found any documentation about this on Microsoft site, but in a blog [here](https://raunaknarooka.medium.com/make-life-simpler-use-managed-identities-part-1-ea9b89f888d8).

Microsoft does have documentation though on roles that you can use and how to limit them to scope in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#azure-built-in-roles-for-azure-service-bus). Example:

```
az role assignment create \
    --role $service_bus_role \
    --assignee $assignee_id \
    --scope /subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$resource_group/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/$service_bus_namespace/topics/$service_bus_topic/subscriptions/$service_bus_subscription
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. We now have documentation outlining this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#identity-based-connections

Comment: It's worth noting that 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus' is for in-process Azure Functions.  If you using Isolated Azure Functions, you should be using 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus' and you want the version >= 5.0.0

Comment: @DavidYates, Does it work for 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus', because I tried to follow documentation but didn't work for Isolated?

Comment: @Viorel.  Yes.  I did get it working for Azure Functions with .NET 6 and isolated functions.  A couple of things to check 1) It requires that the managed identity and YOU have the following roles in the service bus: 'Azure Service Bus Data Receiver' and 'Azure Service Bus Data Sender'  You need these roles because YOU are the managed identity running locally.  2) With isolated Azure Functions make sure your connection string is in the local.settings.json when running locally.  Unless they've fixed in .NET 7, there some weirdness around connection strings for service bus when debugging locally.

Comment: @DavidYates, thank you for help, I fixed yesterday. My issues was in 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus' version was under 5.0.0 and I can't figure out what was going wrong. Locally I started the project at least but on environment, it just read the value from '__fullyQualifiedNamespace' but not found as connection. And yes, on locally something strange happened but I change namespace connection with string connection which point on another service bus.

Comment: Thanks, upgradiong my package to version 5.x allows me to use managed identity, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Agreed that from azure function we cannot access the resource like ASB directly. However, one still does not need to put in the password in this case "SharedAccessKeyName" in the connectionstring directly.
Azure function can work with Azure KeyVault. Thus one can store the connectionstring with sensitive information as a secret in the KeyVault and then grant System assigned identity from azure functions access over KeyVault and then specify the value for the settings in the portal as 
**@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={theSecretUri})**
Details on how to achieve the above is mentioned in the following blog.
https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b

This will still avoid specifying the connectionstring directly in Azure functions and provides with single point of access via Vault to be disabled in case of a security breach

Comment: Yes, keyvault reference is a really nice feature that I am looking forward to becoming generally available. Unfortunately it is still in preview at the moment (Aug 2019), so I am a bit hesitant to putting it to use in production yet. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references)

Comment: There is a built-in way now with the latest package, please see my answer below